# presentModalView coming in from the side in my landscape app

Tags: iphone, ios, view, orientation, landscape

I have a UIViewController that I would like to show with `[self presentModalViewController:settingsController animated:YES]`.

My application is in landscape mode. When I use `presentModalViewController` the view slides in from the side as if it where in portrait mode. When I add the view using `addSubview:` it appears on the screen correctly.

I do use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in my view controllers but it doesn't seem to help with this issue.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Has anyone run into this or know where I might have went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try presenting the modal view from your main view controller and not from a controller of one of the subviews. That did the trick for me.